# jQuery input checkbox filter on products

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've written a small script that currently only runs hide() on the products when the checkbox is clicked. I can't seem to figure out how to only show those specific products with those class names when clicked. If nothing is clicked all products should show.

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/mzvNL/

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li class="menu-item">
    <label for="beans-palak">Beans Palak</label>
    <input id="beans-palak" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="bengal-lentils">Bengal Lentils</label>
    <input id="bengal-lentils" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="bombay-potatoes">Bombay-Potatoes</label>
    <input id="bombay-potatoes" type="checkbox" />
</li>
```

```
<article class="post beans-palak">asd</article>
<article class="post bombay-potatoes">asd</article>
<article class="post bengal-lentils">asd</article>
<article class="post bombay-potatoes bengal-lentils">asd</article>
<article class="post bengal-lentils bombay-potatoes bengal-lentils">asd</article>
```

CSS:

```
article {
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
background: red;
margin: 10px;
display: inline-block;
```

}

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.post').show();

$('.menu-item').find('input:checkbox').on('click', function () {
    $('.post').hide();

    $('.menu-item').find('input:checked').each(function () {
        $('.post ' + $('li.menu-item').find('input:checked').attr('id')).show();
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add the check and filter by class correctly

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.post').show();

$('.menu-item').find('input:checkbox').on('click', function () {
    var post = $('.post').hide();

    var elements = $('.menu-item').find('input:checked');

    if(elements.length){
        elements.each(function () {
            post.filter('.' + this.id).show();
        });
    }
    else
        post.show();
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mzvNL/1/

Comment: This worked perfectly. Didn't even think of using filter. I tried using the length of the checked but couldn't get it to work.. over complicated things I suppose! Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, the checkbox id is the same of the element class you're trying to show.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.post').show();

$('.menu-item').find('input:checkbox').on('click', function () {
    $('.post').hide();

    $('.' + $(this).attr('id') ).show();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for checkbox change, and show only the boxes for those checked:

```
$('.menu-item :input').change(function(){
    $('.post').hide(); 
    if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
        $('.post.'+$(this).attr('id')).show();   
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mzvNL/3/)